# Show loading image

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I am building a web application using `struts2.` I am having a form the user clicks on submit button and I am processing the form and redirecting back to the same `jsp` page.
I want to add the loading image so as the user can understand the request is being processed.
I tried my way by writing the script after the end of form tag and adding the image inside the form but not able to get it right on submission of form.
I am not using jQuery , so the `$.load()` is not useful for me.
Please can anyone help me in this.

Thanks in advance

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function(d) {
        alert("in");
        d.getElementById('loginform').onsubmit = function () {
            alert("on submit");
            d.getElementById('submit').style.display = 'block';
            d.getElementById('loading2').style.display = 'block';
        };
    }(document));
</script>
```

Comment: As your form is being processed you are reloading the page in which case any use of javascript pre-form submission will be ignored unless you process your form through ajax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a work around to see the loading image. Posting here so that other can be benefited. 
I took a gif image and added it inside a div tag with css property display as block.

```
<div id="loading" style="position:absolute; width:100%; text-align:center; top:200px">
<img src = "images/loading.gif" width="70px" height="70px"/> </div>
```

Then I have written a javascript function which I call on event onload.In this function I am setting the display property to none.

```
function stopLoading()
   { 
     document.getElementById('loading').style.display='none';
   }
```

In my case I am setting display block when I am sending any server request and onload the setting back to display none.

Hope this is helpful for others.

Answer (score 1):

If its a redirection - it means you are sending the content to the server and returning back, which ideally means on submit the current lifecycle of the page ends after posting information and new cycle begin when returning back.

One way to do this is to flush the loading image before you do any kind of business in your code from the server.

In .net we do it with two statements:

```
 Response.Write("your loading image in html format");
 Response.Flush();
```

So even before the whole content is loaded back on the browser, a part of it is sent to the client.

Comment: Thanks Chandra Sekhar Walajapet.....need to check how it can be mapped to javascript

Comment: you need to check how it can be done using struts as the code i have given has nothing to do with javascript, its a server side code.

Comment: But on page Load you need to close the Loading Image.. ??

Comment: Yes you got to close the loading image upon completion of the page load